# AWS Route53- how to set routing policy - using the Java API

Tags: amazon-route53, aws-java-sdk

When I use the Java API to create a record, the default routing policy seems to be "Latency" . I haven't found an obvious way to set this policy to "Simple", for instance , . like I would be able to do on the AWS web UI .

Java API :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/AmazonRoute53.html#changeResourceRecordSets-com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a [Simple routing policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html), you should only set the values in the SDK request that are part of the simple policy parameters. If you set Region, HeathCheck, RecordID or [any of the Latency values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-latency.html), that will make the policy be Latency.

Comment: The approach mentioned above is correct, but in practice, it still doesn't work right.