# AWS Route53- parameters for SIMPLE routing policy using the Java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

A while back, I inquired about how to create a simple ROUTING policy via the R53 java API and received some good advice in : [AWS Route53- how to set routing policy - using the Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047535/aws-route53-how-to-set-routing-policy-using-the-java-api)

Params:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html

I tried implementing this and still have issues. I'm not sure what extra info I'm adding (or missing) - I should have only the required info - as per the API

```
        Change change = Change.builder()
                .action(ChangeAction.UPSERT)
                .resourceRecordSet(ResourceRecordSet.builder()
                        .name(recordFqdn) 
                        .type(RRType.CNAME) 
                        .setIdentifier(recordFqdn)
                        .ttl(300L) 
                        .resourceRecords(resourceRecords) 
                        .build())
                .build();

        ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest request = ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest.builder()
                .hostedZoneId(hostedZone.id())
                .changeBatch(ChangeBatch.builder()
                        .changes(change)
                        .build())
                .build();
        getRoute53Client().changeResourceRecordSets(request);
```

The error is pushing me towards specifying the params for "Latency" policy eg if I specify Region, the call succeeds but the routiing policy would be "Latency" . I would really prefer to have a region agnostic policy.

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.model.InvalidInputException: Invalid request: Expected exactly one of [Weight, Region, Failover, GeoLocation, MultiValueAnswer, GeoProximityLocation, or AvailabilityZone], but found none in Change with [Action=UPSERT, Name=foo.mydomain.net, Type=CNAME, SetIdentifier=foo.mydomain.net] (Service: Route53, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxxxxxxx)

    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:125)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
private static void registerCname(Route53Client route53, String hostedZoneId, String domainName, String cnameValue) {
        // Create the CNAME record
        ChangeBatch changeBatch = ChangeBatch.builder()
                .changes(
                        Change.builder()
                                .action(ChangeAction.CREATE)
                                .resourceRecordSet(ResourceRecordSet.builder()
                                        .name(domainName)
                                        .type(RRType.CNAME)
                                        .ttl(300L)
                                        .resourceRecords(ResourceRecord.builder()
                                                .value(cnameValue)
                                                .build())
                                        .build())
                                .build())
                .build();

        ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest request = ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest.builder()
                .hostedZoneId(hostedZoneId)
                .changeBatch(changeBatch)
                .build();

        ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse response = route53.changeResourceRecordSets(request);
    }
}
```